# +1/-1 randomly distributed in 2D array

Tags: matrix, random, fortran

I would like to create a 4x4 array which is filled randomly with +1 or -1 only in *fortran95*. I found a post that can generate numbers:

```
program rand_test
use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env
real  :: r(6)
integer       :: i(6)

! call init_random_seed() would go here

call random_number(r)

i = -1 + FLOOR(3*r)       ! n=-1 and m=1

print *, i
end program
```

However, this includes 0 which I don't want. Is it possile to remove the 0, if so, how?

Comment: With `use, intrinsic :: ..` this isn't Fortran 95 code.  That said, nothing in that module is used so that line can be happily removed if you do need it to be F95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what @Andrew Morton suggested. Below is the code that does what you want

```
program test_rand
implicit none

real  ::r(4,4)
integer       :: i(4,4)

! call init_random_seed() would go here

call random_number(r)

i = nint(r)*2-1       ! n=-1 and m=1

print *, i
end program
```

Answer (score 2):

For each element in the array, generate 0 or 1 at random, multiply it by 2, subtract 1.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want zero... I am new to coding, I don't quite understand what you are saying...

Comment: (0 or 1) * 2 = (0 or 2). (0 or 2) -1 = (-1 or 1).